# Is there a math symbol meaning "If" or "when"?

Tags: logic, notation, propositional-calculus

To introduce a logic premise normally people use the word *If*, or *Iff* (if and only if). Is there a math symbol with the same meaning?

Comment: Iff = $\Leftrightarrow$

Comment: Yes. $A \implies B$ is a shorthand for ``If $A$, then $B$".

Comment: Not the best graphically, but you could use $\Leftarrow$ for the "if" in "A if B".

Comment: Though of course there is the issue that usually, in the Western world, people read from left to right and $A\Leftarrow B$ is therefore harder to read than $B\Rightarrow A$ to them.

Comment: There is no symbol for 'if' per se, but there is a symbol for 'since': `∵`

Answer (score 1):

You could say that $\implies$ (implies) means *if*, so, $A \implies B$ would mean "If $A$ then $B$", and $A\iff B$ would mean *iff*, so it would mean "$A \implies B \wedge B \implies A$" (or "If $A$ then $B$" **and** "If $B$ then $A$")

Comment: Well if something is true, then what? If you want to say, for example if this $A$ evaluates to true, then you can write $ A \implies \text{true}$, for example.  I don't really understand what you would do with just an *if*. Consider, for example "If $x$ is even, then $x^2$ is even", so you'd write $x \text{ is even} \implies x^2 \text{ is even}$

Comment: Well, for defining a function like you wanted you'd write something like [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/365953/how-do-i-define-a-piecewise-function-in-latex). Note you don't have to have everything using symbols, words are also fine :)

Comment: You can write the word, its a matter of taste. Personally, I do write "if.. otherwise" but it's understandable both ways

Comment: You should note that $\implies$ is not an operator, but rather a notation... In the piecewise example, you *could* write $f(x) = \text{condtion} \implies \text{value}$, and most people would understand what you mean, but it's not popular notation. You should note that everything here just means notation, and is a way for mathematicians to write certain stuff. And back to the piecewise example, it was chosen that the notation would be like I've linked above, just for simplicity.

Comment: I think you should make an effort to understand what people are saying before replying to them. I give up. I agree with your answer BTW.

Answer (score 0):

"B if A" is "if A, then B".

Thus, we may symbolize it with:

> $A \to B$.

Also "B when A" is "if A, then B".